# Weird space on top of the listview after updating iOS to 15

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using
Xamarin.Froms: 5.0.0.24125
Xcode Version: 13.0 (13A233)
Visual Studio for Mac Community Version 8.10.9 (Build 3)
NuGet Version: 5.9.0.7134
Xamarin.iOS Version: 14.20.0.27 (Visual Studio Community)

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ListViewTopSpace.MainPage"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             Title="Page title"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
              BackgroundColor="Blue"
              HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,0.5"
                                     Padding="10,0"
                                     BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                            <Label FontSize="12">
                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span Text="User Id: "
                                              FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                         <Span Text="{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label.FormattedText>
                            </Label>
                             <Label FontSize="12">
                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span Text="User name: "
                                              FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                         <Span Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label.FormattedText>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ListViewTopSpace
{
  public class MainPageViewModel : ObservableProperty
  {
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
     Users = new ObservableCollection<UserListModel>()
     {
       new UserListModel { Id = 1, Name = "User 1" },
       new UserListModel { Id = 2, Name = "Test user 1" },
       new UserListModel { Id = 3, Name = "User 2" },
       new UserListModel { Id = 4, Name = "Test user 2" },
      };
     }

    private ObservableCollection<UserListModel> _users;
    public ObservableCollection<UserListModel> Users
    {
      get { return _users; }
      set
      {
        _users = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Users));
      }
    }
   }

  public class UserListModel
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public class ObservableProperty : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
      var handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
       handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
   }
}
```

Result:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKn29.png
This highlighted space shouldn’t be there.

Answer (score 13):

@Colex is right, but you have to replace this string of code:

```
Control.TableHeaderView = new UIKit.UIView(frame: new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 0, float.MinValue));
```

with this:

```
Control.SectionHeaderTopPadding = new nfloat(0);
```

Full code of Renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView), typeof(LVRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace.iOS
{
    public class LVRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        public LVRenderer()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SectionHeaderTopPadding = new nfloat(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as answer....

Comment: However, it breaks in some older iOS. In my case version 12.5.5. So make sure to test.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related with apple not xamarin side .

Please see this thread : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683980.

To solve it we can add a custom renderer for ListView

Try the following code

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView),typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace Formssss.iOS
{
    public class MyRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        public MyRenderer()
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if(Control != null)
            {
                Control.TableHeaderView = new UIKit.UIView(frame: new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 0, float.MinValue));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @colex-msft, thank you for your reply, I've applied above renderer and now space is gone BUT something happened with listview, now, it doesn’t show any record, I've just applied renderer nothing change anything else.

Answer (score 3):

After updating to xamarin.forms version to latest from NuGet manager will solve this issue.

Updating to version 5.0.0.2244 will definitely fix this issue
and extra top padding from list view will be removed on iOS 15.0 or greater