# Xamarin Forms: Blank space is showing on top of Listviews in ios platform

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin.forms

On top of my all listviews in a project, there is a blank space on the ios platform, no such issue on android or windows.

**My code:**

```
<ListView 
        x:Name="MyItems"
        RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
        HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout
                            Orientation="Vertical"> 

                            <StackLayout
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                                
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.Footer>
            <Label/>
        </ListView.Footer>
    </ListView>
```

**Additional Details:**

- XF version: **4.8.0.1821**
- Project type is **Portable**

Comment: You mean like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69304244/weird-space-on-top-of-the-listview-after-updating-ios-to-15

Comment: @BasH Let me check this, will update you soon

Comment: @BasH The custom Renderer solves the problem, could you please update it as your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this thread : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683980.

To solve it we can add a custom renderer for ListView

Try the following code :

```
    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView), typeof(LVRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace.iOS
{
    public class LVRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        public LVRenderer()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SectionHeaderTopPadding = new nfloat(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Found it here :

[Weird space on top of the listview after updating iOS to 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69304244/weird-space-on-top-of-the-listview-after-updating-ios-to-15)

Answer (score 1):

The current accepted answer breaks on iOS 14.7.1, it creates the error "UIKit_UITableView_set_SectionHeaderTopPadding_System_nfloat - unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Here is a modified version that will work.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView), typeof(LVRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace.iOS
{
    public class LVRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        public LVRenderer()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null && UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(15, 0))
            {
                Control.SectionHeaderTopPadding = new nfloat(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See why on this related issue: [Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'sectionHeaderTopPadding'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70691614/value-of-type-uitableview-has-no-member-sectionheadertoppadding)

Also see the developer docs for sectionHeaderTopPadding which is denoted as iOS 15.0+: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/3750914-sectionheadertoppadding